# Refactoring old code to use async keyword

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have started refactoring old code to become Async. If the method is not straight forward to async then i'm copying the old method and I create a new MethodAsync(), and then i just upgrade one by one client to use the new async method when I can.

But I would instead like to avoid creating this duplicate methods. So i'm wondering if there is performance issues with the following two scenarios:

1. UPDATE: Ignore point 1
2. Method is async with await keyword(s). But the client is still not async so it is using .Result :- forcing it to sync behavior. Is this way of "forcing" sync behavior more bad than calling a method that does not use async keyword?

Update: The Async State machine created with the async keyword would introduce overhead. So another question would be how much impact does that have, keep in mind this project is huge in the numbers of several thousand methods.

And 4:- Are there any other factors than the creation of Async state machine that comes to play with the performance while the methods are not yet true async?

Comment: I believe async introduces the async state machine so some little overhead is there but in 99 cases neglible. You can use .Result but you should be aware of how exceptions are handled, better to use getAwaiter().Result i believe.

Comment: I.e. getAwaiter.Result will throw immediately i believe and not wrap exceptions in aggregate exceptions https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html

Comment: 1 -> Not sure what the benefit is of just putting the async keyword in front of the method, without returning a Task. really prepare you should make your method return Task or Task<T>.

Comment: 1 is wrong: you should add [async](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) to method signature *only* if it contains `await`, you should get a compiler warning otherwise. [Msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) has a nice illustration of what happens if you use `async/await`. Also check [Stephen Clearly](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) articles regarding the topic, I have fear your `MethodAsync()` is a code-smell.

Comment: @sommmen when await is used without the method returning a Task I doubt there will be any state machine.

Comment: Never ever use .Result or .Wait, you are introducing some really bad design doing that and may cause deadlocks.

Comment: 2 => if you are using result and combine async and synch calls in a mixed caller hierarchy you are risking deadlocks. If you start with async/await you need to pull it through the entire calling hierarchy

Comment: "Method has Async keyword, without any await keywords. The method will run sync," no it won't! it will start this method and then immediately continue with the next statement without waiting for the method to finish! this might lead to unexpected race conditions

Comment: @MongZhu "2 => if you are using result and combine async and synch calls in a mixed caller hierarchy you are risking deadlocks."

Why would an async method that is forced to be sync risk deadlocks more than just any other sync method?

Comment: async is not for performance of a *single* call, rather for performance of the *whole system* (under some load) - it is making threads available for work that would otherwise be blocked, waiting for some other system to respond

Comment: @Joakim I think [this article](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d) can explain it far better than I could. My comment is based on experience and hours of debugging and error searching in my own code and code by others.

Comment: "Why would an async method that is forced to be sync risk deadlocks more than just any other sync method? " a: "sync context", which is *very well known* to cause deadlock risk in this scenario (note: not all environments use sync context), and b: thread pool saturation; async code is *designed* to release threads when they can't do useful work - that's *why it exists*; if all the workers end up waiting on `.Result`, then *nobody is available to do the actual work*; I cannot emphasize this strongly enough: **DO NOT USE** `.Result` / `.Wait()` (unless you know the awaitable is already complete)

Comment: and yes, I totally understand that adding a proper async API to a sync-based code-base is a lot of work and it doesn't always lend itself to code re-use, because of the different needs of the two approaches; a few months ago I submitted a PR that was "+19281,-525" doing exactly this, so trust me when I say: "yes, I know; it is painful". There aren't any short cuts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the client is still not async so it is using .Result :- forcing it to sync behavior. Is this way of "forcing" sync behavior more bad than calling a method that does not use async keyword?

It's [generally considered an antipattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). The main reason is that [it can cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), depending on the client.

> Update: The Async State machine created with the async keyword would introduce overhead. So another question would be how much impact does that have, keep in mind this project is huge in the numbers of several thousand methods.

Any overhead from the `async` keyword is minimal, compared to the overhead of blocking threads on asynchronous code.

> I would instead like to avoid creating this duplicate methods.

I recommend reading my article on [Brownfield Async Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development); in particular, the "boolean argument hack" is one I've used with some success in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this way of "forcing" sync behavior more bad than calling a method that does not use async keyword?

As mentioned by @mong Zhu, this risks causing deadlocks. Say that the method is awaiting some work that needs to be done on the main thread, calling `.Result` on the mainthread will prevent the main-thread from being used, effectivly deadlocking the application.

> The Async State machine created with the async keyword would introduce overhead. So another question would be how much impact does that have

This is almost impossible to answer since performance spans multiple orders of magnitude. The overhead should be small when doing things Async/await is intended for, i.e. IO operations or compute bound operations sufficiently slow for the user to notice. The general recommendation is as always: measure.

> Are there any other factors than the creation of Async state machine that comes to play with the performance while the methods are not yet true async

The state machine is simply a hidden class with a large switch statement. I have not measured this, but I suspect the overhead of the state machine is smaller than scheduling work on another thread. However, marking a method as async is pointless unless you are not using await. If you are returning tasks but not using await you can either:

1. Return the task returned from another method. Say that you do some initial work and call `ReadToEndAsync` that returns a `Task<string>`, just return the task as is.
2. use `Task.FromResult(myObject)` to create a completed task, or `Task.CompletedTask;`
3. **Edit:** Return a [ValueTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=net-5.0) instead, this is either a task or a TResult. Since this is a struct there is very little overhead to create one.

Comment: on the "If you are returning tasks but not using await you can either:" point - perhaps another option would be "use `ValueTask[T]` instead, as this can very efficiently represent both scenarios (more efficiently than `Task[T]` can)